# determining if iCarousel has switched views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, icarousel

Is there a way to tell if iCarousel has not only activated the

`- (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel`

function, but has also actually physically changed to a different image in the list? I currently have the program detecting scrolling animation changes but i need to know if it actually switched views or if it's just being moved around. They are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the other protocol methods in the [documentation](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/blob/master/README.md):

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's exactly what i needed. And thanks for the docs location

Comment: No problem. Just so happens I was using iCarousel recently so it was still fresh on my mind :)